# How to delete all "Audio" files from my MacBook

Tags: finder, music

Through the disk utility, I can see I have over 10 GB of "Audio" files.
When I search on Finder for music files (kind "Music") no more than 10 MB comes.

What exactly is considered to be "Audio" files?
How can I free up those 10GB?

Comment: Audio files can also contains Audio books, podcasts etc. Not just music. Pretty much all possible audio formats i.e. mp3, aac, wav... and hundreds.

Comment: You can quickly use the kind feature like this `kind:your_search_string`

Answer (score 1):

From within Finder, select the search box at the top right corner of the window and type **Audio**; a list will popup, near the bottom of which will be **Kinds** and **Audio**. Select that type, and then for the scope, select **This Mac**. This will show all the files on your Mac (at least within your Spotlight search's view) that OS X considers to be audio files.

You should be very cautious when deleting files shown this way, as you'll find many are embedded in applications, or used by other applications, including the OS, in various ways; deleting them may render an application dysfunctional.

Comment: Seems this also shows mp4 files which are video with sound.